# Installing mit-scheme alongside postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, mit-scheme

[image] recently started reading [structure and interpretation of a programing language](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) and as such I want to install the mit-scheme interpreter but I realized whenever I installed it, it uninstalled postgres and whenever I installed postgres it uninstalled mit-scheme. My question is how can I install these two packages alongside each other seeing as I use both

Comment: are you sure that there is no other package involved?

Comment: when I run the installation command for mit-scheme it uninstalls  PostgreSQL and when I run the command for PostgreSQL it unistalls mit-scheme .... No other package is invovled

Comment: I have both posgresql and mit-scheme on ubuntu14.04 installed and there is no conflict. Which versions of packages are you trying to install? (mine is 9.1.1-5 for mit-scheme and postgresql 9.3.9-0)

Comment: kindly share the command for installing mit-sheme with me. I mean the version you have .. Because I just do sudo apt-get install mit-scheme  ... I don't specify the version or anything

Comment: I just use my favourite package manager, but you can use the usual 'sudo apt-get install mit-scheme'. And you may want to first run 'sudo apt-get update'.

Comment: @Palo kindly check my screen shot . You would realize it states that the following packages would be removed.

Comment: Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/47003#47003

Answer (score 1):

OK, the situation is more clear now. It seems you are mixing two different architectures. Your screenshot shows libpq5:386 being installed while libpq5 being removed. This results in the whole Postgres being removed as it depends on libpq5. Mit-scheme also depends on that package, but since your Scheme packages are with ":386" postfix, they need the :386 version of the libpq5. However libpq5 and libpq5:386 probably do not like to be installed simultaneously. Install the 64-bit mit-scheme package and you will get rid of the problem.

Comment: I can't seem to find the 64-bit mit-scheme but I came across this http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/  ... which provides SICP support for DR Racket. Hopefully I can get started with the book. Thanks

Comment: Ouch, unfortunately you are right. I was checking my 32-bit machine. On the other one which is 64-bit, it has exactly that kind of conflict you mentioned. :( However as mit-scheme is an open-source project, one should be able to build a 64-bit binary (they have one on their download page anyway) out of the broken Ubuntu package system.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to compile the source yourself. This will "solve" any conflicts from apt-get. Of course, you will not get updates, but the updates for MIT-SCHEME are few and far between.

https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/